# How to Handle Hovering on Robot Framework?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

How can i click on the buttons indicated on the picture below as soon as i hover over an element ?

[image]

As soon a i hover above a table ligne `tr` the segment surrounded by the red appears. i have tried this but it doesn't work

```
${hidden_objs}=  Execute Javascript
...  return document.getElementsByClassName('pull-right')
${select_obj}=   Set Variable    ${hidden_objs[0]}
Wait until keyword succeeds    10s    5s        Set Focus To Element    ${select_obj}
Wait until keyword succeeds    20s    5s        Click Element     ${select_obj}
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: There is a selenium keyword "Mouse Over". Have you tried using it? https://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Mouse%20Over

Comment: @Shnigi Can you give me an example how to use it in my case?

Comment: I didn't understand what you are trying to do so I can't tell more. Please update your problem. Have you tried that mouse over keyword?